# Будет удален Linux, при возврате Windows в исходное состояние?

Tags: linux, windows-10, dual-boot, elementary-os

При попытке загрузить Windows 10 примерно в 4 случаях из 5 нельзя выполнить вход а систему, а в другом случае Windows предлагает разные варианты восстановления/перезагрузки/выключения. Предложенная диагностика не может выявить проблем. Я решил вернуть компьютер в исходное состояние с сохранением всех файлов, но не уверен, останется ли Elementary OS на переразмеченном жёстком диске или Windows "удалит все приложения и программы, которые не поставлялись вместе с компьютером.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы про переустановку винды **средствами винды** со снесением программ и сохранением данных, то таки снесётся только ось, программы и настройки. Другие разделы на диске винда трогать не будет, если вы только сами не попросите. (Если вы перенаправили Program Files на другой раздел, то, вероятно, файлы будут потёрты, но это не ваш случай.)

Тж. см. [список сохраняемых и удаляемых файлов](https://superuser.com/a/1097399) при выполнении "Reset PC" в режиме сохранения личных файлов.

Старые форточки любили "забывать" про другие оси в загрузчике, так что может потребоваться немного сисадминской магии для нахождения других осей после переустановки. Но десятка, вроде, уже более прилично себя ведёт.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы собираетесь сделать откат Windows, все зависит от точки восстановления Windows: На компьютере останется установленный Windows со всеми программами, которые были установлени до точки восстановления. Подробности можете прочитать [здесь](https://hetmanrecovery.com/ru/recovery_news/system-restore-point-windows10.htm).
Но прежде, чем сделаете восстановление, попробуйте войти в безопасном режиме (Safe mode)(http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10). Причиной может быть какой нибудь установленный драйвер, удаление которого может исправить работу системы и откат не потребуется.